# Yii inherit attributeLabels

Tags: yii

With Yii php framework, I use inheritance.

In my AbstractModel, I have this method:

```
public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            '0'=>Yii::t('default','No'),
            '1'=>Yii::t('default','Yes'),
        );
    }
```

In my object who extends AbstractModel, I have this method:

```
public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'username' => Yii::t('user', 'email'),

        );
    }
```

In a view file, I use:

```
<?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($model, $model->property);?>
```

But I never show 'No' or 'Yes' from asbtractModel. If I put all in my model it works. But I want to use inheritance.
How can I concat parent attributeLabels with current model attributeLabels?

Comment: Because you override the method attributeLabels() from parent class. You should merge it like the solution from schmunk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply merge the return value of the parent method in MyObject (model class):

```
  public function attributeLabels() {
    return array_merge(
      parent::attributeLabels(),
      array(
        'username' => Yii::t('user', 'email'),
      )
    );
  }
```

You may also use *CMap::mergeArray()*.